# Sending a lot of SMS programaticaly - problem with delivery reports

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-pendingintent, smsmanager

I have an android app that sends a lot of messages in a short time and the app needs to process delivery reports. And this all works just fine, the app is stable and run without any crashes, messages are sent, delivery reports working fine... fine for some time.

Let's say I am sending a message after messages (each message after previous is successfully sent - I am looking at smsSent PendingIntent - I can send new messages only if hasOnProgressSend == false). Delivery reports work just fine for about 1-2 hours. Then delivery reports behave strangely. Constantly drops several delivery reports.

So after sending is complete, about after 7 hours and about 8000 SMS messages delivery reports stop to come, but there is a lot of messages that are received but the app did not get the delivery report.

But now comes the strange part :). The next day I tried another test and send another 8000 messages. Messages instantly start to come to recipients, but delivery reports I got are from the previous day which does not come to BroadcastReceiver last day. I tried to change my SIM card, and also receive delivery from the previous day sent messages.

After I restart the app it is all same, delivery reports from the last day. But after I restart the device it continues to behave like last day (about 1-2 hrs working fine then delivery reports slow down a lot).

So to summarize:
I receive delivery reports just fine till looks like some device queue is full. After this delivery reports are very slow. Another day when I again start to send (with new SIM card) my delivery BroadcastReceiver gets delivery reports from yesterday sent messages for which yesterday delivery reports did not come. After I restart the app is the same. After I restart the device it starts to behave like the first day. So if my BrodactReceivers are registered in the onCreate method from my Activity, and app restart does not help this must be some android queue problem which I need to handle somehow in my app (maybe to slow down sending, make some more delay after successfully sent a message or stop sending if several undelivered messages are bigger than some value?)

Thank you, and sorry for the huge question :)

I have two BroadcarsReceivers registered in onCreate:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ... check all persmissions
      
        receiverSentGlobal = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                hasOnProgressSend = false;
                
                JSONObject currentMsgSentStatus = new JSONObject();
                try {
                    currentMsgSentStatus.put("msg_id", intent.getStringExtra("msg_id"));
                    currentMsgSentStatus.put("sim_id", intent.getStringExtra("sim_id"));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                switch (getResultCode()) {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        try {
                            currentMsgSentStatus.put("status", "OK");
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                       
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                        try {
                            currentMsgSentStatus.put("status", "GENERIC_FAILURE");
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                        try {
                            currentMsgSentStatus.put("status", "NO_SERVICE");
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                        try {
                            currentMsgSentStatus.put("status", "NULL_PDU");
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                        try {
                            currentMsgSentStatus.put("status", "RADIO_OFF");
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        break;
                }
                sendStatus.put(currentMsgSentStatus);
            }
        };
        registerReceiver(receiverSentGlobal, new IntentFilter(ACTION_SMS_SENT));

        receiverDeliveryGlobal = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                JSONObject currentMsgDeliveryStatus = new JSONObject();
                try {
                    currentMsgDeliveryStatus.put("msg_id", intent.getStringExtra("msg_id"));
                    currentMsgDeliveryStatus.put("sim_id", intent.getStringExtra("sim_id"));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                switch (getResultCode()) {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        try {
                            currentMsgDeliveryStatus.put("status", "DELIVERED");
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        break;
                    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                        try {
                            currentMsgDeliveryStatus.put("status", "CANCELED");
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        break;
                }
                deliveryStatus.put(currentMsgDeliveryStatus);
            }
        };
        registerReceiver(receiverDeliveryGlobal, new IntentFilter(ACTION_SMS_DELIVERED));

    ... 
    }
```

My sendSMS method:

```
SmsManager sm;
... there is also some code to handle subscription, but let's make it more simple
sm = SmsManager.getDefault();


 ArrayList<String> parts = sm.divideMessage(msg);

            Intent iSent = new Intent(ACTION_SMS_SENT);
            iSent.putExtra("msg_id", msgId);
            iSent.putExtra("sim_id", String.valueOf(lastSendSimId));
            PendingIntent piSent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, Integer.parseInt(msgId), iSent,  PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

            //Intent iDel = new Intent(ACTION_SMS_DELIVERED+msgId);

            Intent iDel = new Intent(ACTION_SMS_DELIVERED);
            iDel.putExtra("msg_id", msgId);
            iDel.putExtra("sim_id", String.valueOf(lastSendSimId));
            PendingIntent piDel = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, Integer.parseInt(msgId), iDel, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

if (parts.size() == 1)
            {
                msg = parts.get(0);
                sm.sendTextMessage(number, null, msg, piSent, piDel);
            }
            else
            {
                ArrayList<PendingIntent> sentPis = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();
                ArrayList<PendingIntent> delPis = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();

                int ct = parts.size();
                for (int i = 0; i < ct; i++)
                {
                    sentPis.add(i, piSent);
                    delPis.add(i, piDel);
                }

                sm.sendMultipartTextMessage(number, null, parts, sentPis, delPis);
            }
            hasOnProgressSend = true;
```

**EDIT 1:**
just found - tested by sending messages to 2 numbers. A number is in online device, B is in shutdown device. Till about 250 undelivered messages to B, app is receiving delivery reports for A. After 250 undelivered messages delivery notifications for A is stopped to come to app. After powering B, all notifications came for all messages sent to A an B. So, there is some queue of about 250 waiting delivery reports. Is there any way to limit lifetime of delivery peding itent to about 10 minutes?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found problem. There is limit of about 250 pending delivery intents on device. So I need to limit somehow or cancel old delivery pending intents.